# Proof of the spectral theorem for normal operators from two lemmas

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

I have the following lemmas that I can prove:

1. Let $T$ be a linear operator on a Hermitian space $V$ and let $W$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ . Then $W^⊥$ is $T^*$-invariant
2. Let $T$ be a normal operator on a Hermitian space $V$ , and let $v$ be an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $λ$. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^∗$ with eigenvalue $\bar{λ}$.

From these two I am meant to be able to deduce the spectral theorem for normal operators, but I'm struggling.
The only thing I need to finish my proof is that $V_{\lambda_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus V_{\lambda_k}=V$, or equivalently that the geometric multiplicity of any eigenvalue equals the algebraic multiplicity, or something else equivalent.

I seem to remember the proof we were given a while back following the lines of: one eigenvalue exists due to the fundamental theorem of algebra, so consider finding an orthonormal basis for $V_{\lambda_1}$, then consider $V_{\lambda_1}^⊥$, which is $T^*$ invariant, so...

But I think I might have just remembered wrong? Either way, all of the proofs that I can find on the internet use much higher level ideas, or talk about the sums of upper diagonal matrices, but I'd definitely like to (and should be able to for an exam!) be able to prove it in this way (or at least along these lines).

Sorry for any mistakes!

Edit: I have also that distinct eigenspaces are orthogonal, if that helps!

Comment: It looks like you are in finite dimension. So just prove it by induction on the dimension.

Comment: sorry, do you think you could be a bit more specific? I know it might be simple but for some reason I just can't see it! even if it's a very short answer I'd accept it.

Comment: THere exists at elast an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ so we have the orthognal decomposition $V=V_{\lambda_1}\oplus V_{\lambda_1}^\perp$ which is invariant under both $T$ and $T^*$. So you can apply the induction hypothesis to the restricition of $T$ to the subspace $V_{\lambda_1}^\perp$. You just need to realize that the restriction is still normal.

Comment: ah ok, maybe that's what I'm actually stuck on then; how would one go about proving that it's still normal? would you appeal to the $TT^*=T^*T$ definition or the $<Tv,Tw>=<T^*v,T^*w>$ one?

Comment: With your two lemmas above, you can deduce that both $V_\lambda$ and $V_\lambda^\perp$ are invariant under both $T$ and $T^*$. Then normality on these subspaces is just by restriction of the general normality condition. It is also convenient to see this matricially.